# Auto generate REST api documentation into RAML from Spring MVC controllers

Tags: spring, raml, spring-restdocs, spring-auto-restdocs, raml-java-parser

I am new to Spring-Boot. I want to auto generate my REST api documentation into RAML from my Spring MVC controllers. Is there anything to do that? or any guide that I could use it for generating my rest api into RAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Spring REST Docs to RAML extension for [Spring REST Docs](https://spring.io/projects/spring-restdocs): https://github.com/ePages-de/restdocs-raml However, this project is not maintained anymore and the authors recommend to use their new project https://github.com/ePages-de/restdocs-openapi that converts to OpenAPI (Swagger) instead of RAML. They provide a guide on how to convert OpenAPI to RAML: https://github.com/ePages-de/restdocs-openapi#convert-to-raml There is an example project that demonstrates the conversion to OpenAPI and RAML https://github.com/ePages-de/restdocs-openapi/tree/master/samples/restdocs-openapi-sample One limitation of the extension is that it only works with Gradle at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Florian for the answer. In the meantime there is a maven plugin here. https://github.com/BerkleyTechnologyServices/restdocs-spec - see also the docs for this (https://github.com/ePages-de/restdocs-openapi#maven). Also we plan to refactor `restdocs-openapi` to `restdocs-api-spec`, and eventually we will also have RAML support there.

Answer (score 0):

I know, your Question is outdated, but there is something that might help.

You can use DocDog. From there it creates RAML from the existing source code. If it is SpringBoot you can run it easily with `-lang=spring`. If it is plain JAVA you can add comments to your code (see readme.md or examples), so DogDoc can understand.

May it helps you: https://github.com/skalski/docdog